# How to get transform values using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get the transform values using regular expression. I have tried but it's not working for all the scenarios:

```
var transform = "translate(97.4 12)";

var split = /translate\(\s*([^\s,)]+)[ ,]([^\s,)]+)/.exec(transform);
/*
it given following output,

split[1] = 97.4;
split[2] = 12;
*/
```

But this regular expression not working for following cases:

```
"translate(97.4, 12)"; 
"translate(97.4)";
"translate(97.4,12)";
```

How to get those scenario also using generic way?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details and doesn't provide what you've tried or barely any explanation on what you're wishing to accomplish. Please read the making a good question guide and edit this post.

Comment: Given there is [an API](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedTransformList) that will get you the values this is like asking for a hammer to knock in a screw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
translate\((-?\d+\.?\d*),?\s*(-?\d+[.]?\d*)?\)
```

From [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uQb7ze/4/) the explanation of the regex is as follows

[image: Regex Explanation]

Comment: not working in this scenario,

"translate(97.4)"  it shows   97. and 4

Comment: You are correct! I updated the regex so that the second term is conditional (added a `?` to the second capturing group)

Comment: while giving - value also not working? "translate(13.16976047699518, -5.699114753939966)"

Comment: Yup, I updated to handle your case as well. You should also update your Question with this use case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var transform = 'translate(97.4, 12)';
var reg = new RegExp(/translate\(\s*([0-9\.\,\s)]+)\)/g);

 var value = htmlData.replace(reg, function (a, b, c) {
       return b;
    });


value.split(','); //return value is:  [97.4, 12]
```

also, 
for testing its good to try 
https://www.regexpal.com/

very good and useful site for regex testing